# setTimeout not executing until a form is changed when using ng-class

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using a timeout function in my js:

```
setTimeout(function () {
            $scope.shadow = 'speller-blue';
            currIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
            $scope.currCard = cards[currIndex];
        }, 1000);
```

and I am using ng-class in my html:

```
<input id="speller-box" type="text" class="form-control ng-class:shadow" autofocus="" placeholder="answer" ng-model="answer">
```

I am expecting the code in the timeout to execute after a one second delay and turn the field blue, but the change doesn't happen until the value in the input box is changed.

Comment: You should be using [`$timeout`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout)

Comment: To add to that, $timeout will call a $digest, which is what updates the View. Note that you need to clear javascript timeouts or cancel $timeouts, because otherwise you'll create memory leaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular would't know what `setTimeout` changed until it completes it's next digestion cycle. Either use `$timeout` or manually call `$digest` after you do your changes to the scope.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I think you are doing wrong is that you are applying conditional class but you are using incorrect format

Do something like

```
<input id="speller-box" type="text" ng-class="{'form-control': shadow}" autofocus="" placeholder="answer" ng-model="answer">
```